# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ques')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, jsx, typeerror

Keep getting this error **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ques')**

in FAQ file where the faq.ques is.
if I add faq.src.ques then error shifts to src

everything is correct accordingly but still can't figure it out

any solution???

FAQs file

```
import FAQ from "./FAQ";

const FAQs = () => {
    const[faqs, setfaqs]= useState([
        {
            ques: 'question1',
            subtitle: "st1",
            answer: "answer1",
            open: true
        },
        {
            ques: 'question2',
            subtitle: "Pricing",
            answer: "answer2",
            open: false
        },
        {
            ques: 'question3',
            subtitle: "Pricing",
            answer: "question3",
            open: false
        },
    ]);
    
    const toggleFAQ = index => {
        setfaqs(faqs.map((faq, i) => {
            if(i === index) {
                faq.open = !faq.open;
            } else {
                faq.open = false;
            }
            return faq;
        }));
    }
    return (
    <>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="faq-title">
                        <h1>FAQ</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="faq-content">
                        {faqs.map((faq, i) => {
                            <FAQ faq={faq} index={i} toggleFAQ={toggleFAQ}/>
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
    );
};
export default FAQs;
```

FAQ file

```
function FAQ({faq, index, toggleFAQ}) {
    return (
    <>
        <div className="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div className="panel panel-default">
                <h4 className="panel-title">
                    <div>{faq.ques}</div>
                </h4>
                    <a data-toggle="#collapse" data-parent="#accordion" onClick={()=>toggleFAQ(index)}>+</a>
            </div>  
            <div id="collapse" className={"panel-collapse in" + (faq.open ? " collapse" : " ")}>
                <div className="panel-body">
                   <h5>{faq.subtitle}</h5>
                   <p>{faq.answer}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
    );
};

export default FAQ;
```

...
.

...........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Please add a `"` at the end of `answer: "answer1`. The syntax highlighting is messed up now

Comment: that was in edits not in actual code

Comment: Can you console log `faq` in the `FAQ` file and provide the output here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is array, and you should use faq[i]

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `faq` as `src` and not as `faq`. Just change it to:

```
<FAQ faq={faq} index={i} toggleFAQ={toggleFAQ}/>
```

Comment: I have tried that as well nothing changed still same error

Comment: have you tried logging what the `faq` is?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

1. Quote issue
2. No return on Map
3. key is missing in the map

Please find the updated code.

```
const FAQs = () => {
const [faqs, setfaqs] = useState([
    {
        ques: 'question1',
        subtitle: 'st1',
        answer: 'answer1',
        open: true,
    },
    {
        ques: 'question2',
        subtitle: 'Pricing',
        answer: 'answer2',
        open: false,
    },
    {
        ques: 'question3',
        subtitle: 'Pricing',
        answer: 'question3',
        open: false,
    },
]);

const toggleFAQ = (index) => {
    setfaqs(
        faqs.map((faq, i) => {
            if (i === index) {
                faq.open = !faq.open;
            } else {
                faq.open = false;
            }
            return faq;
        }),
    );
};
return (
    <>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="faq-title">
                        <h1>FAQ</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="faq-content">
                        {faqs.map((faq, i) => {
                            return <FAQ faq={faq} index={i} key={i} toggleFAQ={toggleFAQ} />;
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
);
```

};
export default FAQs;

and for FAQ File

```
function FAQ({ faq, index, toggleFAQ }) {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div className="panel panel-default">
                    <h4 className="panel-title">
                        <div>{faq.ques}</div>
                    </h4>
                    <a
                        data-parent="#accordion"
                        data-toggle="#collapse"
                        onClick={() => toggleFAQ(index)}
                    >
                        +
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className={'panel-collapse in' + (faq.open ? ' collapse' : ' ')} id="collapse">
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <h5>{faq.subtitle}</h5>
                        <p>{faq.answer}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
export default FAQ;
```